# Inside a NeoVim session, quickly edit nvim configuration

Tags: neovim

While I am inside a project session within neovim, I want to edit my nvim config without leaving the current project. Compared to other editors like VSCode or Sublime Text, updating settings isn't that straightforword in Neovim?

Currently I exit the session -> open the init.lua configuration -> edit -> write -> open project folder again...

Comment: ```e: /path/to/init.lua``` and sourcing it with ```source``` won't help?

Comment: I guess I can create 2 keymaps for that...

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the same issue. There are several options I'm finding.

### custom commands with `stdpath()` (for those with a poor memory)

```
" custom commands for easier editing & sourcing neovim config from within neovim
command EditInitVim :exe 'edit' stdpath('config').'/init.vim'
command SourceInitVim :exe 'source' stdpath('config').'/init.vim'
```

My memory sucks and though I've been using VsCodeVim for many years now, I'm relatively new to neovim. So I'm solving it for the time being with these custom commands. I placed the above code inside my `init.vim` config, though for `init.lua` you'll have to make the appropriate changes.

You can use the meat of these commands to bootstrap the commands themselves. Just create a split with `:vsplit` or `:split`. Then manually type in `:exe 'edit' stdpath('config').'/init.vim'`. Paste in the snippet via the clipboard register with `"*p`. Write the buffer (`:w`) then manually enter the source line. The easiest way is to type `:` and then use the up arrow and simply replace `edit` with `source`.

Once sourced (or just restart neovim), you then consume the commands like we did manually above.

1. `:vsplit`
2. `:EditInitVim`
3. make changes...
4. `:w`
5. `:SourceInitVim`

### custom commands with `$MYVIMRC` (slightly less poor memory)

This is the same as the previous, but instead of the function call we use the `$MYVIMRC` variable.

```
" custom commands for easier editing & sourcing neovim config from within neovim
command EditInitVim :exe 'edit' $MYVIMRC
command SourceInitVim :exe 'source' $MYVIMRC
```

`$MYVIMRC` also resolves to `init.lua` if that is your startup script.
~~ATOW I don't know if this resolves to `init.lua`. Someone who uses `init.lua` can check out what `:echo $MYVIMRC` yields and add a comment to this answer and I'll update it.~~

### `:edit/:source $MYVIMRC` (better memory)

No custom command is really required if you can remember the `$MYVIMRC` variable. In my environment (currently windows+wsl2) to edit/source, I can directly type in `:edit/:source $MYVIMRC` and it will open/source the `init.vim`/`init.lua`. The catch is you have to remember the antiquated variable name which in my case is vestigial but at least has "vim" in it. In your case, it's completely different.

For me, I recently learned the `<C-d>` (`ctrl+d`) for listing autocompletions. I have no idea the mnemonic for this (usually vim is so clever with their mnemonics!), but it seems extremely useful so should be learned. It works in this case, where you can type in `:edit $` + `<C-d>` and `MYVIMRC` will be in the list (though there are quite a few others in there).

I welcome neovim power users' comments and improvements!